# PHP Find a pair of elements from an array whose sum equals a given number

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array with n numbers from -10 to 10 (without 0). Implement function which returns quantity of pairs from the array which sum gives 0.

For example:

$input = array (**3**, 6, **-3**, 5, **-10**, 3, **10**, **1**, **7**, **-1**, -9, -8, **7**, 7, **-7**, -2, **-7**);

The right answer is 5 (pairs are bolded)

I made something like this but it gives me 10 pairs:

```
$length = count($input) - 1;
$count = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j <= $length; $j++) {
        if ($input[$i] + $input[$j] == 0) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
}

echo $count;
```

Comment: Does the relationship between 5 and 10 indicate something in particular?

Comment: yes, because right answer should be 5. I got 10 coz my function takes duplicates to final result

Comment: If you think about WHY it counts pairs twice you'll see you can fix this by changing the inner loop's starting number to not be 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php 
$input = array (3, 6, -3, 5, -10, 3, 10, 1, 7, -1, -9, -8, 7, 7, -7, -2, -7);
$length = count($input) - 1;
$count = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++){
    $flag[$i]=0;
}

for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j <= $length; $j++) {
        if ($input[$i] + $input[$j] == 0 && $flag[$i]==0 && $flag[$j]==0) {
            $count++;
            $flag[$i]=1;
            $flag[$j]=1;
        }
    }
}

echo $count;

?>
```

The correct code is given above. Since you have to mark the elements which are already used in making pair. For example, you have two +3 and one -3, which makes 2 pairs since you didn't mark it, that it has already made a pair with existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You did two for loops, so you are counting the pairs twice. You can do some test, every input array you insert in the function will return an even number. Then do `$count = $count/2;` at final.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define why its not working - it is but its finding 7 + -7 6 times: So you need to flag that this match has been found like the below code - with some added output so you can see what is happening:

```
$input = array (3, 6, -3, 5, -10, 3, 10, 1, 7, -1, -9, -8, 7, 7, -7, -2, -7);
$length = count($input) - 1;
$count = 0;
$matched = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($input); $i++) {
  echo "<br />Group ".$i.": <strong>".$input[$i]."</strong>, ";
    $groupmatch = 0;
    $matchon = "";
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($input); $j++) {
        echo $input[$j].", ";
        $check = $input[$i] ."+". $input[$j];
        if ($input[$i] + $input[$j] == 0 && !array_search($check,$matched)) {
            $count++;
            $groupmatch++;
            $matchon .= $check.", ";
            array_push($matched, $check);
        }
    }
  echo "<br />Groupmatch: ".$groupmatch."<br/>";
    echo $matchon."<br />";
}
echo $count;
```